# Add-Ons On Tor Browser

Tags: add-on

Is it possible to have Add-On on Tor browser to directly download videos from the net? I have tried downloading a Firefox Add-On like VideoDownloader.net but it doesn't seem to work on Tor Browser? Help will be much appreciated and a link can also be of essence.

Comment: Are you using Tor for reasons of anonymity? If so, then the recommendation is that add-ons should be avoided: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBOtherExtensions. Also, download videos from where? MP4/MPEG files themselves, or do you mean convert YouTube-like embedded videos to downloadable files?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tor in order to stay anonymous, installing new add-ons is highly discouraged as they can compromise your privacy and security and/or might break the functionality of the browser. As such, there is no official support for these types of configurations. See recommendations [here](https://support.torproject.org/faq/#faq-3) and [here](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/plugins/):

> Installing new add-ons may affect Tor Browser in unforeseen ways and potentially make your Tor Browser fingerprint unique. If your copy of Tor Browser has a unique fingerprint, your browsing activities can be deanonymized and tracked even though you are using Tor Browser.
>
> Basically, each browser's settings and features create what is called a "browser fingerprint". Most browsers inadvertently create a unique fingerprint for each user which can be tracked across the internet. Tor Browser is specifically engineered to have a nearly identical (we're not perfect!) fingerprint across its users. This means each Tor Browser user looks like every other Tor Browser user, making it difficult to track any individual user.

Comment: You are right, but I can't help but see you fell into the "No! Wrong question! Do something completely different than what you asked instead" mindset on stack exchange.